# When using H2 Auto_server mode, is it possible to bind the socket to localhost?

Tags: h2

The [documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#auto_mixed_mode), implies that the connection is always remotely available, but since I use this on a laptop, and change networks, sometimes the clients don't know how to connect, since they are trying to use an IP that is no longer valid.

So, the question is: Is there any way to force H2 to only listen on localhost for auto_server=true?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can set the [server bind address](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html?highlight=bind,address&search=bind%20address#server_bind_address) using the system property "h2.bindAddress".

Comment: Where would you be able to set this inside Intellij? I have added the exact same mix-mode address inside Intellij, but every now and then calls to re-open H2 from within Intellij fail with: `Error: Connection to H2 - testdb failed. Connection is broken: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out: 10.37.129.2:9090" [90067-195]`. Tried to set `-Dh2.bindAddress=127.0.0.1` in the VM options tab of Intellij for DB connections, to no avail. String is `jdbc:h2:/tmp/testdb;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;AUTO_SERVER_PORT=9090` for all web service JVMs, which works fine for them, but not always for Intellij.

Comment: Sorry I don't know, as I don't currently use Intellij. You may want to search for "IntelliJ set system property", I'm quite sure this question was already asked and answered.

Comment: Would you consider adding a flag `AUTO_SERVER_BIND=127.0.0.1` as a feature in future releases?

Comment: @Moreaki I suggest you create a pull request